# Tx-Rx synchronisation to frequency changes

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio

So I am part of an SDR project using GNU Radio and USRPs, where we are trying to set up a link between USRPs.

The ideal is similar to the DARPA spectrum challenge (https://spectrumcollaborationchallenge.com/). We are trying to change the tx_frequency in order to avoid interference or signal jamming. I am looking for a method or a protocol to implement to synchronise rx with tx's frequency changes.

Comment: Do you have any information about the tx's frequency changes? Is it following a specific pattern or Is it just randomly hopping through the frequency band?

Comment: I can set the pattern. I am allowed to transmit within a 3Mhz bandwidth (1811 - 1814 Mhz) so for starters I split it in two and send 100-200 packets at each band and so on. It doesn't work so far so any ideas are more than welcome

Comment: Does it work if you stay on the same frequency the whole time?

Comment: without interference yes

Answer (score 3):

that looks like it's a Cognitive Radio challenge.  so, if a frequency is already in use, you want to find an idle frequency to use instead.  you could use something similar to ALE (Automated Link Establishment)  where all radios in a network keep track of what frequencies are usable, what frequencies are in use, and choose a frequency to communicate with another specific station, or to send allcall/anycall requests.  look on github for examples of cognitive radio